# Assassinate the Reptiloid sidequest... what are the consequences?

Tags: paranoia-happiness-is-mandatory

The game is working! I'm extremely paranoid about the result of completing or not this sidequest.

What are the outputs of this side quest? I know I can ignore this quest or kill him. Are there other options?

[image: Side mission]

EDIT about options: You can ask if the "Reptiloid" person does not like the way the computer actions and tell your Loyalty Officer to take over the conversation.

> He will jump in front of the train to suicide.

Yet, I don't know the consequence of this action.